# Origin has been blocked by CORS policy send 413 (Payload Too large)

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, api, wildfly

I hosted my spring boot project wildfly server and reqseted to api with large body from angular front end .but there has not hitiing the backend and browser console like below.
I tested the same body in locally. It is working.

[image]

My spring project controller as follows

```
 @PutMapping(value = "{userRoleCode}/tasks/{pageCode}", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, produces =
        { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> assignPageTasks(@PathVariable String userRoleCode, @PathVariable String pageCode,
        @RequestBody List<TaskDTO> taskList, @RequestAttribute(value = "username") String username)
    {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(userRolePrivilegeService.assignPageTasks(userRoleCode,
            pageCode, taskList, username));
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like it's being blocked by a policy on the host, and probably has nothing to do with your application, given that it works locally.

I suppose that your two choices are to either figure out how to change this config on your host (possibly in a proxy server, such as Apache or NGINX), or break up your data and send it in smaller chunks over multiple POSTs.

Note that it's not specifically a CORS error, you are simply seeing that because of the 413 response lacking the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: A case of firewall policy applied on the request payload.

Comment: Thank you for your cooment. i will check my server